# Quantum-Classical Hybrid theories: How useful are they?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mesoscopic-physics

I have seen several attempts at building a consistent quantum-classical theory, i.e., a theory where a quantum (sub) system interacts with a classical one somehow.
Examples: (1) https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/442/1/012006.
(2) https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04787

However, they tend to focus more on theoretical aspects and less on application to real systems. I guess, hybrid theories are supposed to give a good approximation in mesoscopic systems, where some things are big enough to be considered classical but not that big that all quantum effects can be ignored.

So, in what actual physical systems (not toy models) do quantum-classical theories give good results for practical calculations?

Comment: Do you include the Wigner function approach as “hybrid”?

Comment: By themselves, Wigner functions are fully quantum. However, there are hydrid systems that works by mixing the classical phase space (classical sector) with the wigner function formalism (quantum sector). https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.7036

Comment: You can treat the photoelectric effect in a semi-classical way, with the atom being quantum mechanical and the incident electromagnetic radiation treated classically. See Lamb and Scully "The photoelectric effect without photons," in "Polarization, Matière et Rayonnement," Volume in Honour of A. Kastler (Presses Universitaires de France, Paris, 1969)

Comment: However, *physically*, not mathematically, the mainstream view is that all of Nature should ultimately be treated quantum mechanically, without an arbitrary split between classical and quantum.

Comment: @AndresB To clarify: which way do you want the influence to go? We commonly use models in which the classical ingredients influence the quantum ones. Examples include quantum particles influenced by a classical EM field, a quantum EM field influenced by a classical current, quantum fields influenced by a classical spacetime metric, and so on. Are you asking about models in which the influence also goes the *other* way? Such models have fundamental self-consistency problems, but they can still be useful for estimating things. Do you require strict self-consistency?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly  I'm asking for models where the classical and the quantum sectors influence each other.  I know there are consistency problem with this kind of models (including violation of conservation laws https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1628.pdf) and I don't mind, they are just an approximation after all. I'm just looking for situations in which hybrid models give good results in application to actual physical systems.